# customizing vimrc for functions and commands defined in plugins

Tags: vim, plugins

Sometimes, customisation of vim utilising plugins' functions and commands increases the efficiency of using vim largely. And I was told it can be done by using conditional settings. For example, if I want to mapping some keys only when the plugin tabular is installed, I can write something like

```
if exists(":Tabularize")
    vnoremap ......
endif
```

into my ~/.vimrc file.

But because the starting sequence of vim is to load ~/.vimrc before plugins. These settings will only turn out not loaded. Is there a work around for it? Or how should I validly make these conditional settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised another way, maybe more neat, as I can put all the script in `.vimrc` like rest of the configuration using this method(I want to make this configuration file as portable as possible). The idea behind it is simple, with `autocmd` for the event `VimEnter`. We can load some scripts after all plugins are loaded.

First define a function in the file `.vimrc`, and put all plugin specific behaviour in it.

```
function! g:LoadPluginScript()
"Tabular
    if exists(":Tabularize")
        vnoremap foo
        bar
    endif
"plugins A
    if exists("some_function_or_variable_defined_in_plugin_A")
        foo
        bar
    endif
endfunction
```

then, add an `autocmd` somewhere after this function to call it on event of `VimEnter`

```
augroup plugin_specific_script
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * call LoadPluginScript()
    foo bar
augroup END
```

And that's it. All plugin specific scripts will be successfully loaded after enter Vim, as long as the responsible plugins are available.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new file called `~/.vim/after/tabularize.vim` and put your script in it. Any files ending in .vim in the ~/.vim/after directory are loaded after the plugins are loaded, but before vim actually starts.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_initialize_plugins found it in the wikis of vim. Thanks.

Comment: This will work as long as the plugin itself isn't defined in the after/ subdirectory. This is quite rare, but sometimes it happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
runtime plugin/tabthingy.vim " I don't know the plugin name
```

If your plugin is loaded by a plugins manager, you'll have to add this line (and the following test) after the configuration of your plugins manager.

Otherwise, IIRC, I've seen plugins managagers (or was it google's maktaba framework ?) that can execute things after the correct loading of plugins. But I guess the first solution should be enough.